Angular 18 in VSCode devcontainer renders blank page on ng serve
I'm working with a Win11 WSL2 PC.
Trying to launch an Angular 18.1 app within a devcontainer with latest Node, after ng new, ng serve I open localhost:4200 I get nothing but a blank plage, not items in network, not errors in console, just a blank html page.
When I try with a Angular 16 in devcontainer with appropriate Node version it works perfectly
Repro steps:

open VScode in wsl, create a devcontainer Node Typescript instance with last angular/cli
ng new, answer questions, app is scaffolded
ng serve, open localhost, found out it renders blank page

Expected:
When I start a devcontainer with same conditions in github, it renders the angular 18 app-root component.

This question is similar to: Angular application running in a container not accessible from the browser. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
